# Can Neural Networks Output Numbers > 1?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

Usually when training a Network to decide between two values from a given data `2` things I have noticed.

**1.)** Two output neurons per decision are used and by favoring the neuron with the higher value a **+ve** decision is made.

**2.)** A single neuron per decision against a certain threshold say `0.5` hence a **+ve** decision is made by checking if the neuron outputs a value **>=** `0.5`

Say one wants  the network to make predictions based on the input data such as predicting the centroid of a shape from a given image each time what can one do other than making the output neurons the possible number of outcomes(which is definitely the entire number of pixels x `2` due to `X,Y` value pairs possible).

Specifically How can one make the output neurons fire e.g. (`432,50`) as the centroid in this case say the possible centroid (`X,Y`) coordinates are from `0` to `450` **[** in other words can artificial neurons be modeled to behave like the [Grandmother Cell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandmother_cell) if not then why **]** ?

Comment: You can let the 0 and 1 represent binary positions of a numeric value. Say you have 10 output neurons, then you can make values up to 2^10 (1024). Alternatively you can let the decimal values represent a thousand multiplier, meaning 0.5 would be 500, 1.0 is 1 000 etc.

Comment: you should learn how NN works, check : https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning (see particularly linear regression)

Comment: the set range range that you speak of is not because nodes but rather the activations on them , namely softmax or Sigmoid or other similar functions which themselves have a range from 0 to 1 , if you dont use an activation then your result wont be limited

Comment: If you stumbled upon this question without any satisfactory answer also check [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/how-to-transform-inputs-and-extract-useful-outputs-in-a-neural-network) and [there](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24872/can-i-have-a-neural-network-output-values-100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scale your [0,1] output to the range you want.

If you want your output to be X ∈ [0,500] and Y ∈ [0,500], you can have 2 outputs that both outputs [0,1] and multiply each result by 500.

You should also scale your input data to some uniform range. Some functions require that the input is in a specific range (e.g. [0,1]) and, for example, having some input sets in [0,10] and some in [0,1000] may confuse the network or having different features in different ranges could make it harder for the network to weight the features appropriately.

If your output is in the same range as your input, determining by how much to scale the input will also tell you by how much you need scale the output.

Comment: I don't  quite get your answer. I get you saying I should scale the output by 500 if range is from 0 to 500. so if the output is 0.999 that's `0.999 * 500` but I don't  quite get how that would work for training towards getting the centroid as per the problem above. Like I mean what would the label look like using one-hot label encoding e.g. if centroids from 3 images are (234,300), (300,200) and (420,480) what would the label look like, obviously definitely not [0,1], [1,0], [0,1] right?

Comment: @LiNKeR Your training labels doesn't have to be just 0 or 1 (well, it might be, depending on the implementation you're using, but it's not a general rule). You could consider the distance between the output and the label (`abs(output-label)`) for training.

Comment: just took a look at this again and I realized I didn't quite catch your explanation then. Is it correct if I understand what you meant to be that I should have only two output neurons whose results have to be multiplied by 500. So for instance if outputs results e.g. `X(0.689)` and `Y(0.42)` that would be `X(500*0.689=345)` and `Y(500*0.42=210)` so will that mean my output label for training for this particular xy-value-pair would be real-numbers  **[** `345,210` **]** or fractions **[** `0.689,0.42` **]**

Comment: @LiNKeR Yes, 2 output neurons and multiply the results by 500. For training labels it'll probably be the numbers in the range [0,1], although this might be implementation dependent. Just make sure you're using the correct scale at the correct place - you don't want to be comparing neural network output you have multiplied by 500 by training data you have not multiplied by 500, and you don't want to pass something in one scale that expects another (backpropagation would probably expect a value between 0 and 1 for the error, for example).

Answer (score 3):

You're question contains two components

1.) can a neural network learn concepts like GrandMa. The answer is yes, however, the approach taken is typically different from what you have described. The branch of ML is called representation learning. In simple terms the typical concept is as follows: A vector is used to describe all concepts. Each entry of the vector corresponds to a neuron of the neural network. However, concepts do not directly map onto individual neurons. One could enforce that, but it wouldn't make sense.

2.) Can neural networks predict numbers. Indeed like in the other answer you can use output normalization -- this is map the target values on the number range 0-1 and denormalise afterwards. However, this has the drawback, that it will take a very long time until your neural network converges to the extreme values. An alternative and much easier approach is to use a neural network for regression. The idea is basically to not use a squashing function like relu in the output layer, but for example a linear activation function.
The following function for example predicts two columns in `iris` using Keras

```
iris = load_iris()
idf = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                     columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])

X = idf[["sepal length (cm)","sepal width (cm)","target"]] #this is ugly including class not ordinal
Y = idf[["petal length (cm)","petal width (cm)"]]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=3,
                activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(X.values, Y.values, epochs=1000, verbose=1)
Yp = model.predict(X.values)
#print([Y.iloc[:,0],Y.iloc[:,1],Y.iloc[:,0]-Yp[:,0],Y.iloc[:,1]-Yp[:,1]])
plt.scatter(Y.iloc[:,0].values,
                        Y.iloc[:,1].values)
for (x,y,dx,dy) in  zip(Y.iloc[:,0].values,
                        Y.iloc[:,1].values,
                        (Y.iloc[:,0].values-Yp[:,0]),
                        (Y.iloc[:,1].values-Yp[:,1])):
    #print(str(x)+" "+str(y)+" "+str(dx)+" "+str(dy))
    plt.arrow(x,y,dx,dy)
plt.show()
```

[image: unnormalized predictions]